# ajax response with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

i can not get a response in ajax. I know I am hitting the correct route because it is responding to the correct log on the back end. But I can not get res.end to work. i tried other ways as well an example being from this post. [How to return success from ajax post in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820734/how-to-return-success-from-ajax-post-in-node-js).

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/register",
      method: "POST",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: { email: email, type: "checkCount" },
      success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.status + " status of result"); // does not display result...
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText;
        console.log(errorMessage);
      },
    });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var postFunctions = require("../public/postFunctions/register");

router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.render("register");
  })
  //@param dm = decisionMaker for post -- dm = req.body.type -- type in switch -- response made
  .post(function (req, res) {
    let dm = req.body.type;
    switch (dm) {
      case "registerForm":
        res.send("uploadData");
        break;
      case "checkCount":
        console.log("should be an error message"); // this displays fine so i know route works
        res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}'); //not sure why not showing in ajax result
        break;
      default:
        res.send("action failed. type not found");
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be res.send u have used res.end .Please use correct syntax.
res.end() will end the response process.

Comment: res.send({"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200});

Comment: I just didn't have logging activated on the browser...